# Is it possible to change a Swift package from a library to an executable?

Tags: swift, package

I wanted to code a small command line tool as a Swift Package but executable. At start I made a Package with the following command.

```bash
swift package init
```

And now after I finished my work I realised, that the command does create a library and not an executable. Now my question is: Is there a way of changing this with help of the Package.swift manifest?

I already tried changing the `Package.swift` to executable:

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "lookupTool",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .executable( // <---- Here changed to executable
            name: "lookupTool",
            targets: ["lookupTool"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .executableTarget( // <---- Here to executableTarget
            name: "lookupTool",
            dependencies: [],
                exclude: ["test.txt", "test2.txt", "test3.txt"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "lookupToolTests",
            dependencies: ["lookupTool"]),
    ]
)
```

but it is not working.

I cant run `lookupTool` as an executable in the `./build/debug` folder where the executable exists. If I type the command `ls` the executable is there.

Comment: "I cant run lookupTool as an executable." What did you do to conclude that you "can't" And did you get any errors?

Comment: If I go the the main Folder of the Package and run the command "swift build". Then change the directory to ".build/debug", where the executable exits if I look into with "ls" command. But if I run it will not found the command "lookupTool": "zsh: command not found: lookupTool". Sorry i didn't answered correctly. I deleted and changed the answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: It's not on your path. Did you do `lookupTool`? It should be `./lookupTool`.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. !! Thank you @Sweeper

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been resolved in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

To run your executable, there are a couple of options. If it is already built, you can run it directly. From your package directory you would type

```
.build/debug/lookupTool
```

Or you can `cd` to the directory and run

```
./lookupTool
```

This is the solution suggested by [Sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper). The reason you need to add a directory path (even `./` is a directory path) is that neither `build/debug` not `.` will be in your `$PATH` variable. Do not ever put `.` in your `$PATH` variable, by the way. It's a very easy exploit.

The other way to run your executable is (from the package directory)

```
swift run lookupTool
```

This has the advantage of building the product before running it. So, it's good as part of your build - test cycle. You can also type

```
swift run -c release lookupTool
```

which will build ands run the optimised release version of your tool. This latter is the same as building the target for release and then typing `.build/release/lookupTool`